# Thinking "icon" remains "turning" on YouTube video after the video is playing. What's the fix?

Tags: youtube

When I play some YouTube videos the "thinking wheel" remains in the centre of the video still thinking even though the video is loaded and playing properly.  In some videos everything is normal.

What is causing this?

I did update Flash yesterday. Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly buffering issue, guess your Internet speed is slow, would recommend you that whenever you try to play any video, just pause it, let it buffer, when you see a grey line filled up, you can start playing that video.

Comment: That's the thing it stays even though half the video is loaded and playing smoothly.

Comment: hmmm, now thatlil weird, why don't you download the videos and see it ofline? Buffering &issue downloading takes same time.. & more over you can watch that video anytime without buffering..

Comment: Where is the download button in Youtube?

Comment: @Hoque You can't download YouTube videos directly, you need a downloader for that, for example Internet Download Manager.

Comment: @Hoque You Welcome :)